# Cannot read property 'blackbox' of undefined - AutoForm and Meteor

Tags: meteor

Here's my schema:

```
TestCollection = new Meteor.Collection('test_collection');

var Schemas = {};

Schemas.TestCollection = new SimpleSchema({

  servicesSelected: {
    type: [Object]
  },

  "servicesSelected.0.selected" : {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: false
  },
  "servicesSelected.0.sku" : {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  "servicesSelected.0.title" : {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  "servicesSelected.0.price": {
    type: Number,
    optional: true
  },
  "servicesSelected.1.selected" : {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: false
  },
  "servicesSelected.1.sku" : {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  "servicesSelected.1.title" : {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  "servicesSelected.1.price": {
    type: Number,
    optional: true
  }

});

TestCollection.attachSchema(Schemas.TestCollection);
```

My Template:

```
<template name="test">

{{#autoForm validation="keyup" collection="TestCollection" id="order-submission-test-form" type="insert"}}

    <h1>Doing everything manually and specifying the data-schema-key:</h1>

    <input type="checkbox" name="servicesSelected.0.selected" data-schema-key="servicesSelected.0.selected">
    <label>HDR Photos</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="servicesSelected.1.selected" data-schema-key="servicesSelected.1.selected">
    <label>Panos</label>

{{/autoForm}}

</template>
```

Whenever I click on the checkbox or try to validate the form I get a **Cannot read property 'blackbox' of undefined** error in the console. What am I doing wrong?

`servicesSelected` is supposed to be an array that contains hash tables on each index.

So something like:

```
serviceSelected = [

  { 
    selected: true,
    sku: "123",
    title: "title1",
    price: 100 
  },

  { 
    selected: false,
    sku: "124",
    title: "title2",
    price: 150 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, I would try getting rid of all numbers within your sub-object definitions. So I would try doing `"servicesSelected.$.selected"` instead of `"servicesSelected.0.selected"`.

Worked for me, hopefully it works for anyone else with this strange issue.